# Would a page modified twice within the same second break If-Modified-Since?

Tags: rest, http, caching, http-1.1, if-modified-since

From my understanding of the caching mechanism, the response header `Last-Modified`, request header `If-Modified-Since` and etc has accuracy to the second, i.e. `If-Modified-Since: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT`, and thus subsecond modifications would undermine invalidation:

```
12:00:00.100 /path/to/resource updated to Version 1

12:00:00.200 GET /path/to/resource from client A
12:00:00.300 Response: Version 1 of the page with Last-Modified: 12:00:00

12:00:00.400 /path/to/resource updated to Version 2

12:00:00.500 GET /path/to/resource from client A with If-Modified-Since: 12:00:00
12:00:00.600 Response: 304 Not Modified

# and even after time passes
16:15:00.000 GET /path/to/resource from client A with If-Modified-Since: 12:00:00
16:15:00.100 Response: 304 Not Modified
```

And until the cache expires, the client would not ever get Version 2 of the page.

Is this actually the case? Should versions stored in the page always increase the last modified date of the page by one second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the one-second resolution of `Last-Modified` means that validation requests with `If-Modified-Since` can return the inappropriate value if the resource changes in less than a second. Your example is correct.

The specification acknowledges this, and gives [rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.2.2) for when a `Last-Modified` header can be considered a strong or a weak validator. You can read more about that distinction in the specification, but essentially it's saying explicitly that the validation could fail (be weak) unless the client or server can be sure that it won't (by comparing the `Date` and `Last-Modified` headers, for instance).

The solution, though, is not to lie about the `Last-Modified` time, but to use an `ETag` instead. It doesn't suffer from this sub-second resolution problem, and is [explicitly recommended](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3) as an alternative in this case:

> An entity-tag can be more reliable for validation than a modification
> date in situations where it is inconvenient to store modification
> dates, ***where the one-second resolution of HTTP date values is not
> sufficient***, or where modification dates are not consistently
> maintained.